# How can I block all files in a directory except for 1 file in a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is an example of my directory tree:

```
private-folder/
├── .htaccess
├── foo
│   ├── secret-codes.json
│   └── secret-ruby.rb
└── bar
    ├── snafu
    │   ├── proxy.php
    │   ├── client.php
    │   └── testdata.xml
    ├── config-file.php
    ├── secret-access.php
    ├── PUBLIC-ACCESS-FILE.php
    └── top-secret.php
```

I want all files to be hidden except for the file labeled `PUBLIC-ACCESS-FILE.php`

Here is my htaccess:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "/bar/PUBLIC-ACCESS-FILE.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

This is not working as the file still shows 403. Is there a way I can do this all in one file? What is the best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with two rules. The first one allows `PUBLIC-ACCESS-FILE.php` and the second rule hides everything else

```
RewriteRule ^bar/PUBLIC-ACCESS-FILE.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```